# How do I profile a program running on a mobile device running windows ce?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, profiling

I have a vb.net project that I'm working on in VS2008 that I would like to do some performance analysis on. I am deploying the program to a mobile device running windows ce and need a way to do analysis on it. How do I do this and also what tool would you recommend or is this possible through VS2008.